# Why does this create table SQL work in MSSQL Server but not on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to `SQL` and I just can't figure it out. I'd be glad to get some help. Thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE messages(
  sender INT REFERENCES users(id),
  receiver INT REFERENCES users(id),
  message VARCHAR,
  sendtime TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT pk_messages PRIMARY KEY(sender, receiver, sendtime)
);
```

This is the error code:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
>
> 'sendtime TIMESTAMP,
> CONSTRAINT pk_messages PRIMARY KEY(sender, receiver, '
> at line 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL *needs* length to be specified in the `varchar` column:

```
create table messages (
    sender int references users(id),
    receiver int references users(id),
    message varchar(100), -- change 100 based on your needs
    sendtime timestamp,
    constraint pk_messages primary key (
        sender,
        receiver,
        sendtime
        )
    );
```

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html

In MSSQL, there is a default length 1 if not specified.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176089.aspx